# Node/Express, passing data to the front-end

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

Having a particularly hard time getting this to work. I've read the countless other posts on this subject (most of them using a front-end framework, or rendering the view from an express templating engine (.ejs, .jade, handlebars, etc.). I'm using a basic .html file with ajax.

I  have an express app which I use to request and parse data from an external API. the "/" route serves up the .html page, and I also have a '/getDeviceStatusAll' route that sends the GET request to the API and parses/formats the response into an array. I would like to serve this array to my front-end, which displays this data in a nice searchable table.

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const port = 1337;
var reqs = require('./reqs.js');
var logger = require('./logger.js');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    logger.log('homepage loaded.');
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/wallboard.html'));
});

app.get('/getDeviceStatusAll', (req, res) => {
    //api request to retrieve device status for all devices.
    let d = reqs.getDeviceStatusAll();
    res.send(d);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    logger.printTime('Application started.');
    logger.log('Application started.');
})
```

**reqs.js (just another module to organize the code for the GET request)**

```
var request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

var method = 'GET';
var ds_URL = 'https://example.com/api/getDeviceStatus';
var APIKEY = 'TmlGd0lMUxxxxxxxxxYjhNM3djUT09';

var ds_options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'url': 'https://example.com/api/getDeviceStatus', 
    'headers': {
        'apikey': 'TmlGd0lMxxxxxxxxxxxYjhNM3djUT09',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    }, 
    body: '{\r\n"devices" : "*"\r\n}'
};

var reqs = {    
    getDeviceStatusAll: function(){
        request(ds_options, function (error, response){
            if(error) throw new Error(error);
            var body = JSON.parse(response.body);
            var data = body["Data"];
            dataArr = [];
            for(obj of data){
                delete obj["unwanted_col1"];
                delete obj["unwanted_col2"];
                dataArr.push(obj);
            }
            fs.writeFileSync('./data/getDeviceStatusAll.txt', dataArr);
            return dataArr;
        })
    }
}

module.exports = reqs;
```

**front-end views/wallboard.html:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:1337/getDeviceStatusAll"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    th{
        color:#fff;
    }
</style>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="bg-info">
        <th>Bus:</th>
        <th>Is Online:</th>
        <th>DRID:</th>
        <th>Status:</th>
        <th>Last Contact:</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">
        
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var dataArray = [];

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/getDeviceStatusAll',
        success:function(response){
            dataArray = response
            buildTable(dataArray)
            console.log(dataArray)
        }
    })

    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable")

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].Bus}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].Online}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].DRID}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].State}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].LastOnline}</td>
                        </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row

        }
    }

</script>
```

When I load up my "/" route, nothing is returned. Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is the issue here. Your `reqs.getDeviceStatusAll` has no return value.

```js
let d = reqs.getDeviceStatusAll();
res.send(d);
```

But because requests take a callback you cant just simply say return. You have to pass a callback like

```js
// reqs.js
...
var reqs = {    
    getDeviceStatusAll: function(callback){
        request(ds_options, function (error, response){
            ...
            callback(dataArr);
        })
    }
}
```

and

```js
// app.js
...
app.get('/getDeviceStatusAll', (req, res) => {
    // res.json could also be used here
    reqs.getDeviceStatusAll(dataArr => res.send(dataArr));
});
```

###### Edit for comment:

"Nevermind- got it working (I didn't see one of your corrections). Although IE is complaining of Syntax error in the first ` of my template literal, it works in chrome... and that's all that really matters right?"

This happens because IE doesnt support your template literal

```js
// views/wallboard.html

// not supported in IE
var row = `<tr>
    <td>${data[i].Bus}</td>
    <td>${data[i].Online}</td>
    <td>${data[i].DRID}</td>
    <td>${data[i].State}</td>
    <td>${data[i].LastOnline}</td>
</tr>`

// use this instead
var row = "<tr>";
row += "<td>" + data[i].Bus + "</td>";
row += "<td>" + data[i].Online + "</td>";
row += "<td>" + data[i].DRID + "</td>";
row += "<td>" + data[i].State + "</td>";
row += "<td>" + data[i].LastOnline + "</td>";
row += "</tr>";

table.innerHTML += row;
```

Comment: Well, closer! now my wallboard.html page sits "spinning" and "waiting for localhost". When I check the dev options/f12, network tab, I see my GET request to http://localhost:1337/, protocol "pending", result/description "pending"... nothing contained in the body of the payload.

Comment: Nevermind- got it working (I didn't see one of your corrections). Although IE is complaining of Syntax error in the first ` of my template literal, it works in chrome... and that's all that really matters right?